# How to find the nearest value in a column from one table to a specified cell in another table ensuring it is on or after a given date?

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, excel-formula, match

I hope someone can help me write an excel formula for my problem.

I have two tables:

Table A

| ID | TYPE | Date | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | ABC | 02-Jun-23 | 997 |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | ABCEX | 08-Jun-23 | 27294 |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | ABCEX | 10-Jun-23 | 943 |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | ABCEX | 17-Jun-23 | 1000 |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | ABCEX | 17-Jun-23 | 1000 |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | ABC | 25-Jun-23 | 86000 |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | ABCEX | 25-Jun-23 | 4849 |

Table B.

| ID | Date | base | newnumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | 01-Jun-23 | 29000 |  |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | 05-Jun-23 | 950 |  |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | 11-Jun-23 | 999 |  |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | 21-Jun-23 | 1009 |  |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | 21-Jun-23 | 85000 |  |
| CNWIUBETOBNSO482 | 21-Jun-23 | 4760 |  |

[image]

Here is what I'd like to have in Column K, "newnumber":

So for cell K1, I'd like to have the nearest value to J1 that is in column D, if:

- the IDs match
- the date in table A for that row is on or after the date for the cell in I1
- the type ends in "EX"

Each cell from column D from table A can only be used once to be input into column K.

So ideally it would look like this if it works:

[image]

Notice that cell K5 has no value because there are no values that are after the date in cell I5 from table A that haven't already been used by the other cells in column K - this is the thing I am struggling to wrap my head around most. Also note that cell K6 is empty because, although there is a close number in column D, the type does not end in "EX" and there are no other values that haven't already been used.

Thank you, I hope that makes sense. Any questions for further clarification needed from me would be appreciated.

I really had no idea where to begin. I tried a =IF(And(...)) statement combined with ISNUMBER(SEARCH(...) but this kept giving me all N/As after countless attempts.

Comment: Please add the sample data in markdown format for us to copy/paste to excel and work with.

Comment: OK done that now, sorry for delay

Comment: Your `TableA` got duplicated rows (4 and 5). Is that correct?

Comment: yes that's correct, this is likely to occur within dataset

Comment: 2nd question from my end: So how did you determine that K5 is empty because the value of 4849 is used prior? Since chronologically it is not true. If one would work chronologically then K6 and K7 should both be empty whereas K5 should contain 4849.

Comment: I should have made that clearer. The values assigned to the column K should be prioritsed based on how near the numbers in column D are, not prioritised by time. So once the nearest number has been assigned within the list, it cannot be used and the next closest would then be assigned, (as long as its after the corresponding date.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with Excel365 I'm pretty sure it's a lot easier with FILTER, but anyways, this may work for you:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$8;SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($A$2:$A$8=H2)*--(RIGHT($B$2:$B$8;2)="EX")*--($C$2:$C$8>=I2)*--(ABS($D$2:$D$8-J2)=MIN(ABS($D$2:$D$8-J2)))*ROW($D$2:$D$8)))-1);"-")
```

The formula is an array formula, so it must be entered pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or it won't work properly.

[image]

Notice my argument separator is `;`

Comment: I hope you don't mind, would you mind explaining the logic behind the formula you have provided very briefly, i.e, just what each function is doing if that's possible?

Comment: This might not work as expected. Change the value in D8 to 1000 and you'll see why.

Comment: Ah good spot, you are correct.

Comment: @JvdV Forgot to add the formula must be entered as array formula. If i change the value in D8 to 1000, cells k5 and k7 return 1000 because that value matchs all conditions. I'm not able to see why you say this might not work as intended

Comment: The problem is that `K5` ***and*** `K7` will retrieve 1000. However, there is only one valid option of 1000 to choose from, namely `D8`. The question is atmittedly very complicated. Just deleted my answer, since there is still a bug in there too.

Comment: @JvdV So you mean K5 and K7 should not return 1000? They should return no value? And yes, I agree with you that question is complicated.

Comment: Yes, if we would change `D8` to 1000. In that case 1009, so `K5`, would get a newnumber 1000, `K7` should stay empty since `D8` is now used and no longer available. The question messes with the brain, but look at it this way: The 1st cell to fill in `K2:K7` was `K3` since this would be the closest `ABS()` match against all possible numbers in `D2:D8` considering all conditions. When `K3` is filled out, it would effectively make the search range for the next smallest match `D2:D4` and `D6:D8` scrapping the used `D5`.